# How to pass post param value with & included using curl

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to make a curl request with post parameters. Below is the curl request:

```
curl -d "name=abcdef&ghi&age=20" <http://f1.com>
```

The name parameter value contains `&` character and it is acting as a delimiter. Is there any way to include & in the parameter values??

Comment: Try to put single quotes around the & symbol. Like `curl -d "name=abcdef'&'ghi'&'age=20" <http://f1.com>`

Answer (score 0):

To use an an Ampersand symbol (&) in a URL it must have the proper encoding (%26).

Replace the & in the name parameter with  %26 in your URL and you should be fine.